# Angular UI bootstrap uibModalInstance.result not yielding any value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is my code for the directive `cabinet` and my two controllers `CabinetThumbnails`,`ModalCtrl`. Based on my requirement i am using the directive `cabinet` and the `CabinetThumbnails` to render couple of widgets and then on click of every widget using `ModalCtrl` to open a popup. The Widgets are generating fine, pop-up is opening fine too but `(uibModalInstance.result.then(function (thumbnailData))` is not working. So , its not hitting the service too `cabinetService.getComments(thumbnailData)`. What's wrong here ?couldn't figure out.

```
function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .directive('cabinet', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                controller: CabinetThumbnails,
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                bindToController: true,
                link: link,
                templateUrl: 'app/cabinet/cabinet.directive.html',
                scope: {
                    thumbnail: '='
                }
            };
        });
    function link(scope, el, attrs) {
    }

    CabinetThumbnails.$inject = ['$scope','$uibModal','cabinetService'];

    function CabinetThumbnails($scope,$uibModal,cabinetService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.showImage = showImage;

        activate();

        function activate() {
        }

        function showImage() {
            var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/components/capture/cabinet.pop-up.html',
                controller: ModalCtrl,
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    thumbnailData: function () {
                        return vm.thumbnail;
                    }
                }
            });

            uibModalInstance.result.then(function (thumbnailData) {
                spinner.spinnerShow();

                //call the service to get the comments
                cabinetService
                    .getComments(thumbnailData)
                    .then(function (data) {
                      $scope.comments = data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        growl.err('Unable to open the screen shot, Please try later !', {ttl: 20000});
                    })
                    .finally(spinner.spinnerHide);
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        }
    }

    ModalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'thumbnailData', 'growl'];

    function ModalCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, thumbnailData, growl) {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.thumbnailData = thumbnailData;
        ctrl.cancel = cancel;

        function cancel() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: You are expecting thumbnailData resolve to be passed to your uibModalInsrance.result promise callback. I don't think that is correct. Try just passing vm.thumbnail to cabinetService.getComments instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i moved the service call to the referencing controller, it got resolved and worked.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('cabinet', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: CabinetThumbnails,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            link: link,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/capture/cabinet.directive.html',
            scope: {
                thumbnail: '='
            }
        };
    });
function link(scope, el, attrs) {
}

CabinetThumbnails.$inject = ['$scope','$uibModal'];

function CabinetThumbnails($scope,$uibModal) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.showImage = showImage;

    activate();

    function activate() {
    }

    function showImage() {
        var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/capture/cabinet.pop-up.html',
            controller: ModalCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                thumbnailData: function () {
                    return vm.thumbnail;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

ModalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'thumbnailData', 'growl','cabinetService'];

function ModalCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, thumbnailData, growl,cabinetService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.thumbnailData = thumbnailData;
    ctrl.save = save;
    ctrl.cancel = cancel;

    //call this method to get executed while the directive loads to open the pop-up
    getComments();

    function getComments()
    {
        cabinetService
            .getComments(thumbnailData)
            .then(function (data) {
                ctrl.comments = data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                growl.err('Unable to get comments, Please try later !', {ttl: 20000});
            })
    }

    function save() {
    var form = $scope.cabinetForm;

        if (!form.$invalid && form.$dirty && form.$valid) {
            var data = {
                CabinetFileID: ctrl.thumbnailData.CabinetFileID,
                Comment: ctrl.inputcomment
            };
            //call the service
            cabinetService
                .addComments(data)
                .then(function (data) {
                  //refresh the comments by calling the getComments method again
                    ctrl.thumbnailData.CommentCount = ctrl.thumbnailData.CommentCount + 1;
                    getComments();
                    ctrl.inputcomment = '';
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    growl.err('Unable to add comment, please try later !', {ttl: 20000});
                })
        } else {
            growl.info('Please enter the comment');
        }
    }

    function cancel() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    }
}
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple things to consider:

1. First of all you don't need to use `controllerAs` when you're defining the modal, in ui-bootstrap you should just use `controller: myModalController as vm` (or in your case ctrl instead).
2. In your directive however you're defining `controllerAs: 'ctrl',` but you later use `vm`.
3. In you modal controller you are only using the `$uibModalInstance.dismiss()` method, the dismiss method closes the modal and activates the promise rejection handler for the `uibModalInstance.result` promise.
   You should use `$uibModalInstance.close()` to activate the resolve handler. otherwise all that code wouldn't run.

I would have written it like this

```
   spinner.spinnerShow();

   $uibModal.open({
       animation: true,
       templateUrl: 'app/components/capture/cabinet.pop-up.html',
       controller: ModalCtrl as ctrl,
       size: 'lg',
       resolve: {
           thumbnailData: function () {
               return ctrl.thumbnail;
           }
       }
   }).result
        .then(function (thumbnailData) {
            //call the service to get the comments
            return cabinetService.getComments(thumbnailData);   
        }, function() {
             $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        }).then(function (data) {
            // we get to this 'then' after cabinetService.getComments finished
            $scope.comments = data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            $log.err('Unable to open the screen shot, Please try later !', {ttl: 20000});
        }).finally(spinner.spinnerHide);
    }
```

And add

```
ctrl.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close(valueForResolveHandler);
};
```

to ModalCtrl

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion , but i already tried moving the service call to the actual referencing controller and everything worked smooth. I will try your approach too. thank you !